# python paramiko not connecting to hostname as parameter

Tags: python, paramiko

I have a file with a list of routers that i connect to. For some reason when i read the file and loop through the list of routers and try to use paramiko to connect it doesn't work. It fails with the following error:

```
socket.gaierror: [Error -2] Name or service unknown
```

But if i take one of the hostnames and put it directly in the connection parameter it work no issues.

Not working when looping over hosts.txt file

```
with open("hosts.txt", "r") as f:
   for line in f:
       remote_conn.connect(line, username=username, password=password, look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)
```

Works if i do it like this

```
remote_conn.connect("test-r-1", username=username, password=password, look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)

hosts.txt file
test-r-1
test-r-2
```

Comment: So you can connect with Paramiko. You obviously have a problem a file contents or with parsing the contents. I'd guess that the issue is with line endings.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are providing invalid hostnames. You should provide IPs of the routers in your file.